# How to edit link properties as underline color in ExactTarget content editor?

Tags: marketing-cloud, css, html

Can't find how to change link underline color in content editor. It seems that ET content editor putting underline to all text links by default and you can't remove them at all + link color is decalred as separate font tag not inside off a tag:
    Download the new, free white paper today

Answer (score 1):

ExactTarget's editor is not spectacular, which is why it's in active development for complete overhaul.

Currently, you will need to modify each link color in the wysiwig, or edit the HTML directly.